# Excel 2010 VBA Match function is not finding a match

Tags: excel, vba, match

In Excel 2010, my MATCH statement below is not working. The function should return the row number of a dataset identified by the datasetId (which should be unique) and 0 if the datasetId is not present. Whether the datasetId is present in the first column or not, the function always goes to the second branch and returns 0

```
Function findDataset(dataWorksheet As Worksheet, datasetId As String) As Integer
    If Not VBA.IsError(Application.Match(datasetId, dataWorksheet.Columns(1), 0)) Then
        findDataset = Application.Match(datasetId, dataWorksheet.Columns(1), 0)
    Else
        findDataset = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Are you using the function in a **VBA** sub or a worksheet cell??

Comment: *What* is the Error value returned from the MATCH function?

Comment: I'm using it in a sub. The Error code is 13 (type mismatch)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with your function:

```
Function findDataset(dataWorksheet As Worksheet, datasetId As String) As Integer
    If Not VBA.IsError(Application.Match(datasetId, dataWorksheet.Columns(1), 0)) Then
        findDataset = Application.Match(datasetId, dataWorksheet.Columns(1), 0)
    Else
        findDataset = 0
    End If
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim id As String, n As Integer
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    id = "XX"
    n = findDataset(ws, id)
    MsgBox n
End Sub
```

Works for me..............perhaps your match is not EXACT.

Comment: The match should be exact because even if I create the dataset directly before I get the same result

    Sub MAIN()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim id As String, n As Integer, lastRow As Integer
        Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
        id = "XX"
 
       lastRow = dataWorksheet.Range("A" & dataWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        dataWorksheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = id
        
        n = findDataset(ws, id)
        MsgBox n
    End Sub